# declare N in float in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I was reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx.
There is a N in the float datatype. But, when I tried to declare N in float in SQL Server 2008, it didn't allow me. Where can I put the value for N?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Martin yep, sorry, did not look closely enough. Still, the question sounds like he wants N to be a constant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
declare @x float(24) , @y float(53)
```

See the Note about other values of `n`

> SQL Server treats n as one of two possible values. If 1<=n<=24, n is
>   treated as 24. If 25<=n<=53, n is treated as 53.

`real` is synonymous with `float(24)` and `float` defaults to `float(53)`

**Edit:**

Regarding the comments. **There is no point!**, try the following.

```
CREATE TABLE FloatTest
(
x float(7),
y float(24),
z float(53)
)
```

Then refresh the list of tables and open the table designer. You will see SQL Server has just converted the first two columns to `real` and the last one to `float` anyway!

Comment: Thanks for reply. How do I do it if I use the SQL Server Management studio?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Create a table with these `datatypes` via the UI? If so just select `float` or `real` from the dropdown as these are the only 2 options anyway.

Comment: I want to specify value of n in management studio for float. But, I can't. I mean same as we do in decimal.